# C#: showing unique characters in a string only once

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with repeated letters. I want letters that are repeated more than once to show only once.

Example input: **aaabbbccc**
Expected output: **abc**

I've tried to create the code myself, but so far my function has the following problem:

If the letter is repeated more than once it doesn't show up in the final string.

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string word = "Hello World!";
    Console.WriteLine(encode(word));
}

static string encode(string word)
{
    string result = "";
    word = word.ToLower();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        result += (word.Split(word[i]).Length - 1 > 1 ? ' ' : word[i]);

    return result;
}
```

I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Compare characters with the previous one. To do so, start the loop at the second character.
`static string RemoveRepeatedCharacters(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
        return "";
    }
    s = s.ToLower();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(s[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i - 1]) {
            sb.Append(s[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}`

Comment: Do you just want a list of unique characters, or do you want to remove characters that repeat contiguously? For example, should "abba" return "aba" or "ab"? Should "A man, a plan a canal, panama" return "A man, a plan a canal, panama" or "A mn, pl c"?

Comment: @aquinas The space character is repeating in your second example... :)

Comment: `static string Encode(string input) { return input == null ? null : string.Concat(input.ToLower().Distinct()); }`

Comment: The duplicate this question points to seems to have a sensible answer. However, if you wanted to do it by hand with reasonable performance, you could do as follows: create an empty dictionary of <char, bool>; check the first letter of your string for whether it is in the dictionary already; if it is, repeat with the next character, otherwise, add it to both output string builder and dictionary, then repeat with the next character. Once the whole input string is processed, return a string from your string builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static string encode(string word)
{
    return Regex.Replace(word , @"(.)\1+", "$1");
}
```